# How can we reassociate the existing page object with a new browser after closing its browser

Tags: page-object-gem

Sometimes the browser gets stuck and does not respond (this is reported to be a known issue with the refresh operation on Firefox)
In these cases, I can still proceed by doing a browser.close and re-opening a new browser.
The problem is that the current page object still points to the old browser.  Is there any way to recreate the browser of an existing page object without destroying and recreating the whole page object?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying browser is stored in the page object's @browser variable. This variable normally gets set by the `initialize_browser` method. In theory, you could call that:

```
# An existing page object instance
page = MyPage.new(browser)

# A new browser
browser2 = Watir::Browser.new

# Change the browser in the page object instance
page.initialize_browser(browser2)
```

Unless you are setting other instance variables in the page object instance, I do not believe this is going to much more beneficial than just re-initializing a page object instance (ie doing another `page = MyPage.new(browser2)`).